# 'Class.function' doesn't exist in current context while using a self made NuGet Package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have created a NuGet package on .NetCore class library and accessing it from another .net core class library. I can't call my public and static method from a public and static class even tho the class name is detected.

One point to make is that the Package works on a Console App properly, but I am having trouble in accessing funcions in a class library.

To create a package I went to property->Package->Create Package on build and also nuget.exe method. Both lead to the same thing

Both the package and the new project are .net core 3.1 class libraries

Can someone please help me out

NuGet package code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TrailCorePackage.helper
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static void print(string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Code while calling the function in another class library

```
using System;
using TrailCorePackage.helper;

namespace ClassLibrary5
{
    public class Class1
    {
        Utility.print("value");
    }
}
```

Error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   IDE1007 The name 'Utility.print' does not exist in the current context. ClassLibrary5   C:\Users\---\ClassLibrary5\Class1.cs    Active
```

Comment: please add your sample code into your question, not with external links because it can become invalid in the futur.

Comment: Applied the said changes. @sodjsn26fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't comment yet, I'll add it like answer. Have you added a reference to your package into your console app?

UPD.

I've just noticed that you are calling function inside the class body. It won't work. Something like this will probably work.

```cs
using System;
using TrailCorePackage.helper;

namespace ClassLibrary5
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void AnyMethod() 
        {
            Utility.print("value");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I can install the package in a console app and use the same without any errors. A problem occurs when I try to install the same package in a class library. I have installed the package and added the namespace used. The name of the class is being detected and getting autocompleted but the functions are not.   
While calling new Utility() it declares that I cannot call a static class, so I think I have added a reference but still there is a problem in getting to the function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just noticed that you are calling function inside the class body, you can't do so. You should declare any method and use that in it. You can't call function directly in class body. I'll edit my answer for more correct answer.

Comment: Oh my god. I have been working with C# for a while and I think this is the part where I jump off from somewhere :'( . I was so convinced that it had something to do with building the NuGet package that I missed never thought of checking the code. And obviously it worked in the console app cause I was calling it inside main. 
Thank you so much for this can't tell how grateful I am.